# How to obtain a 0 Attack IV ditto?

Tags: pokemon-sixth-generation

I'm doing a test in pokemon village because my ditto friend safari is lost. I have a fainted synchronize Quiet Ralts in 1st slot. 
I know that for level they are at in pokemon village, I need the exact speed star of a 0 IV, winning a speed tie means it has the 0 Speed IV. I also know that for testing HP IVs you need a pokemon with final gambit that is sure to outspeed the pokemon and with 1 hp less than desired.
How would I go about testing for attack stat? Using foul play?

Comment: *Foul Play* is based on enemy's attack, but you'll need its defense and HP to figure out the actual Attack IV, so it's not recommended. If you are looking for a 0 Attack Ditto you need luck, you can find one with a chance of 1/31, nothing else.

Answer (score 1):

The only sure fire method I can think of, as Ditto's attacks are entirely given by Transform, is to have a Pokemon with only one move, and use it's stats, along with the damage calculator, to figure out a scenario where if the Ditto has 0 attack IV that move will always deal a set amount of damage, different than if Ditto had any other IV value. Good luck finding this combination though, you'll probably find it quicker to simply catch every Ditto that matches the other things you're looking for and have them rated for that 1/32 chance.

Comment: 1/32. The IV can be anything from 0 to 31, which is 32 different values.

Comment: @scenia Ah yes, I had forgotten it can be zero. Updated the answer.